# R webscraping a number of tables from a page

Tags: r

I am trying to webscrape the 5 tables on the page: www.lme.com/copper.asp

I can webscape the whole page but I am having problems scraping the tables into proper dataframes without HTML formatting.

```
library(XML)
lme.cu <- readHTMLTable('http://www.lme.com/copper.asp',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? When I run this, I see the tables just fine in `lme.cu[[11]]`, `lme.cu[[13]]`, etc. Granted, the tables need to be cleaned up a bit, but that's the nature of the beast with web scraping.

Comment: I am trying to remove the  HTML formatting that I get as well eg \r\nÂ  12\r\nÂ, so I just get the numbers in a dataframe.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a locale issue? I'm not seeing any HTML, really. I see currency symbols and some punctuation that needs cleaning ($8,500.00), and a lot of strings with extra white space and newlines (`\n`), but not much else. It all seems fairly easily handled with gsub, as Tyler mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually requires reqex stuff.  Sorry but that's part of the art of scraping.  My two favorite regex related functions for scraping/cleaning are `gsub` and `strsplit` as in:

```
gsub("Â", "", "edsÂedfde", fixed=TRUE)
strsplit("e/d/sÂedfde", "Â", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]
```

The commas in your numbers are going to need to be deleted as well if you want the data to be numeric.

**EDIT:** I also suggest you check out some work my friend Bryan has been doing with parsing HTML data here [(LINK)](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/24292-Parsing-HTML).

Comment: gsub("\\n", "") ;  gsub(",", ".")  and  gsub(" ", "")  are also a good start i guess